# how to type function reference in typescript

Tags: typescript, memoization, typescript-generics

Given the following function `getCards` - How do i declare a type for the input of `memoize`? It takes in a reference to a function.

```
import memoize from "fast-memoize";

function getCards<T>(
  filterBy: string,
  CardsList: T[] = CardsJSON.map((item, i) => ({ ...item, id: i }))
) {
  return CardsList;
}

// This is what i've tried.
// const testType: Array<ICard> = getCards<ICard>("test");

const fn = memoize(getCards);
```

I also get the following type error for CardsList and i can't figure out what the error is..?

> TS2322: Type '{ id: number; spId?: string | undefined; callToAction?: string | undefined; cardTags?: any[] | undefined; campaignId: string; cardTitle: string; cardDescription: string; endAgeLimit?: number | undefined; ... 37 more...; updatedAt: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
>         Type '{ id: number; spId?: string | undefined; callToAction?: string | undefined; cardTags?: any[] | undefined; campaignId: string; cardTitle: string; cardDescription: string; endAgeLimit?: number | undefined; ... 37 more ...; updatedAt: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that the compiler cannot guarantee that the types are reconcilable when the function is called, consider this example:

```
getCards<User>("name");
```

Here the `T` is explicitly set to `User` but the card list will be defaulted to essentially `Card & { id: number }`, so they will not match.

---

I thought this might be fixable by putting a constraint like the following on the type parameter but unfortunately that does not work:

```
function getCards<T extends Card & { id: number }>
```

This does not quite work because the type is used as the type argument of an array. So if you set `T` to e.g. `SpecialCard` which has a property `bonus` (does not exist on the `Card` type) and you retrieve an item from the default card list, you will not get an object of type `SpecialCard`, as the property will be missing.

Your constraint has to be a subset, not a superset of the card properties, so a generic might not be suitable here at all.